# Ошибка 404 возможно по рефереру

Tags: wordpress, nginx, apache2

Сервер Ubuntu Apache2+Nginx.

При переходе по ссылке на внутреннюю страницу сайта *с другого сайта* выдается 404 ошибка хотя страница существует.
Однако когда тот же самый адрес внутряка вбиваешь в адресную строку все ок.

Всевозможные защиты по referer отключил, не помогло.
Проблемный сайт на Wordpress, там никаких ошибок не вижу.
Включение-отключение кэша не дает результатов.
Отключение кэша в Cloudflare тоже, как и сброс всевозможных параметров защиты.

Внутренняя перелинковка работает корректно, проблема возникает при попытке пройти на сайт по ссылке с другого сайта.

В логах просто ошибка file not found

Не понимаю где искать проблему.

Comment: Закешированный редирект. Или же ссылки разные (например ошибка в написании на доноре)

Comment: С любого сайта, где есть ссылка на внутряк происходит 404.
Но вы натолкнули на мысль о том, что для каждого хоста есть свой nginx.conf если я правильно понимаю. 
Потому что на других сайтах этой виртуалки такого не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!
Некоторое время назад я ставил защиту от hotlink.
Поскольку запросы на хосте обрабатывал не Apache2, а Nginx директива в .htaccess для защиты от hotlink не работала как надо.

Тогда я внес изменения в nginx.conf проблемного хоста:

```
valid_referers none blocked server_names ~(yahoo|duckduckgo|yandex|google|yahoo|bing|facebook|fbcdn|twitter);
        if ($invalid_referer) {rewrite (.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4)$ https://site.com/x.png;
```

блокируя редисок по рефереру на уровне nginx.
После удаления этой директивы ссылки на внутряки перестали отдаваться 404-ми ошибками.

Остается вопрос как сделать защиту hotlink и почему все-таки отдавалась 404 ошибка.